# Can I accurately approximate solutions for m for any k being an integer : $\sum_{n=1}^{k+1} \frac{k ! m^{(k-n+1)}}{(k-n+1) !}-\frac{k !}{2} e^m = 0$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I had noticed that when approximating solutions for $m$ to the above equation for a given $k$, as $k$ grows larger, the solutions $m$ takes the form $m\approx k+c$ where $c$ is some constant. I'm trying to figure out whether this $c$ is really an approximate constant as $k$ approaches infinity.

Comment: Here $m^{(j)}:=m(m-1)\dots(m-j+1)$, correct?

Comment: Do you mean the Arithmetic progression to be $k+c, 2(k+c), 3(k+c), \dots$? Or $k+c, 2k+c, 3k+c, \dots$? Or $k+c, k+2c, k+3c, \dots$? Is this an observation on several solutions $m$ for the same fixed $k$?

Comment: perhaps the OP can be more precise; if the notation is as Pietro Majer suggests, this is just a binomial coefficient; is that what is intended?

Comment: The notation for $m^{j}$ is simply, m to the power of j.. no falling factorials or anything.

Comment: For Claude Chaunier, it would be,  just $k+c$, for any given k..
So for example : suppose k = 1... then $m=1+c$
if k = 2, then $m=2+c$ and so on and so forth. 
Do note ,this is solely looking at the positive solutions for the above equation mentioned for a given $k$

Comment: I managed to simplify the problem to the following : 
Finding the value of m for a given value k for the following equation : 
$\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{m^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{m^n}{n!}$

Comment: I think, after the clarifications by the OP, the question now makes sense: Does $m-k$ converge to finite limit as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand\Ga\Gamma$Your conjecture is correct. Indeed, using repeated integration by parts (see e.g. formula (2.6) in [this paper](https://mia.ele-math.com/23-95/Exact-lower-and-upper-bounds-on-the-incomplete-gamma-function) or in its [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.06384)), we have
$$\Ga(k+1,m)=k!e^{-m}\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{m^i}{i!},$$
where $\Ga(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes, as usual, the incomplete gamma function.

So, your equation for $m$ can be rewritten as
$$\frac{\Ga(k+1,m)}{\Ga(k+1)}=\frac12.$$
That is, $m$ is the median of the gamma distribution with parameters $k+1,1$. So, for all natural $k$
$$k+\frac23<m\le k+\frac23+\frac1{2k+2}$$
-- see e.g. formula (3) in the paper by [Adell and Jodrá](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715204002937?via%3Dihub).
Hence,
$$m=k+\frac23+o(1)$$
as $k\to\infty$. So, your conjecture holds with the approximate constant $c=2/3$.

---

This is illustrated by the following pdf image of a Mathematica notebook, containing the graph $\{(k,m(k)-(k+2/3))\colon k=5,\dots,100\}$, where $m(k)$ is the solution $m$ of your equation for the given $k$:

[image]

---

For related results and further references, see e.g. [this note](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715220303308) and references therein.